# Ansible nested variables | searching in a dictionary

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

Unfortunately, I can no longer get on with a problem. I'm just learning a bit about the world of ansible and I'm trying a few things.
But now I can not get any further.
I have a dictionary in the host_vars:

```
host_test_vars:
   server_type: test_type1
   version: 1.7
```

I want it to use this information to find a link from the defaults that will download the appropriate version.
The defaults look like this:

```
test_default:
   test_type1:
      1.7: https://download-site.com/test_type1-1.7
   test_type2:
      1.8: https://download-site.com/test_type2-1.8
```

How can I easily get the link via the dictionary in the defaults based on these entries in the host_vars?
Thanks for your help in advance

I forgot to show you the task so you can see what I have in mind.

Task:

```
- name: download link
  ansible.builtin.url:
    url: <here needs to be the link from the defaults>
    dest: /folder1/folder2/file.jar
    mode: '0755'
```

Comment: => `{{ test_default[host_test_vars.server_type][host_test_vars.version] }}` - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names

Comment: Quoting: "The defaults look like this", I assume this is `defaults.yml` or some other "globally" available variables @vladimir-botka.

Comment: Be careful with that `version: 1.7` because in yaml that value will be a `float`, whereas the `1.7: https://...` will have `str` keys; thus, you may need `...server_type][host_test_vars.version|str]` instead

Comment: I just updated the question because I forgot to show you my tasks to explain what I want to do

Comment: Okay thank you for the links, I will try it @Zeitounator